# How to solve differential equation $y=xy'+\frac12y'^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve differential equation
$$y=xy'+\dfrac12y'^2$$

Comment: Try $y=ax^2{}$.

Comment: Show your work if you have tried anything.

Comment: There is the trivial solution $y(x) = x + \frac{1}{2}$, but apart from that, no idea.

Comment: Duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2144855/115115, also search for "Clairaut equation" to find related examples.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Differential equation $y=xy' + \frac{1}{2}(y')^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248737/differential-equation-y-xy-frac12y2/).

Answer (score 4):

This is a standard and classical Clairaut differential equation,
$$
y=xy'+f(y').
$$
Besides the straight line solutions 
$$
y=Cx+f(C)=Cx+\frac12C^2
$$
there is also an envelope solution that can be obtained from the derivative of the original equation
$$
0=(x+f'(y'))y''
$$
or $x=-f'(y')$, in this case $x=-y'$ and thus 
$$
y=-\frac12x^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $v(x)=y(x)+x^2/2$. Then $v'(x)=y'(x)+x$, so adding $x^2/2$ to both sides of your DE gives
$$
v=\frac12 v'^2.
$$
I'm sure you can separate $v$ and $x$ here.

Comment: Caveat: If you separate the variables it's easy to forget the special solution $v=0$ (or $y=-x^2/2$).

Answer (score 0):

The attempt $y = Ax^n$ could be interesting.
Then $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = A n x^{n-1}$ and by substituting one gets $$\frac{1}{2} A^2n^2x^{2(n-1)} -Ax^n+ Anx^n = 0 $$
By imposing that $ 2(n-1) = n$ we determine $n=2$, after which we are led to the condition $$ (2A +1)A = 0$$ with solutions $A=0$ (as clearly the trivial solution statisfied your ODE) and $A = -\frac{1}{2}$

In response to the comments below and for completeness's sake, it is also interesting to see an additional family of solutions can be found by the ansatz $y = A(x+b)^n$.
Upon substitution, this yields
$$\frac{1}{2} A^2n^2(x+b)^{2(n-1)} -A(x+b)x^n+ An(x+b)^n = 0 $$
Here the value $n=1$ promises progress by huge simplification, yielding $$\frac{1}{2}A^2 - Ab = 0 $$ so $b = \frac{1}{2}A$, which going back to the ansatz provides the family of solutions $$ y = A(x+\frac{A}{2} )$$

Comment: Good, but there should be a one-parameter family of solutions, no?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, indeed I was sloppy, now has been taken care by better fellows Stackexchangers below.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For quadratic first order differential equation 
$$y=xy'+\dfrac12y'^2$$
we have
$$y'^2+2xy'-2y=0$$
and
$$y'=-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+2y}$$
these two equations solve with substitution $x^2+2y=u^2$ and we have $u=C$. This shows $x^2+2y=C^2$ and putting it in main equation gives us $\color{blue}{y=-\dfrac12x^2}$.